How do I fix my code to correctly calculate the sum of all even numbers in a list?
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
even_sum = 0

for num in numbers:
    if num % 2:  # Incorrect condition for checking even numbers
        even_sum += num

print("Sum of even numbers:", even_sum)

I wrote a Python script to calculate the sum of all even numbers in a list. However, the result is incorrect because the sum includes odd numbers instead of even numbers.
I used the condition if num % 2: to check for even numbers, expecting it to identify all even numbers correctly. I expected the output to be 12 (2 + 4 + 6), but the code includes the sum of odd numbers, resulting in 9.

Welcome to Stack Overflow.  num % 2 returns 0 if divisible by 2, and 1 when not divisible by 2.  So you are essentially saying  if 0: (for divisible by 2) and if 1: (not divisible by 2).  So the former, it will skip, and latter it will go into the condition.  Which is not what you want.

I don't understand why a question was asked. You observed that the condition does the exact opposite of what it's supposed to do, right? But then you ask how to fix it... ? Does "use the opposite condition" actually need to be explained? If the question is really why you get the wrong result from this condition, then you should ask that instead. But we should understand first, in more detail, what your understanding is: where the code says if num % 2:, what do you expect the % to do? What do you think should be the result of num % 2 would be with an even/odd number, etc.?

Try this:
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
print(sum(filter(lambda x : x%2==0, numbers)))

As for your code, you are missing the condition.
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
even_sum = 0

for num in numbers:
    if num % 2==0:
        even_sum += num

print("Sum of even numbers:", even_sum)

